# how to determine whether a property has been changed in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF service which will be invoked by a Java written client. The service can edit an model in our database. While the model has lots of properties, I want the users only set properties which need to be changed besides the ID property. The problem is: in my service side, how can I determine whether a property has been changed?

Answer (score 0):

If you send an instance of a type as part of a service operation request, WCF doesn't have any built in way of knowing if a property is different, even if the client is sending back the same instance of a type which was received as part of an earlier service response.

In order to determine this, WCF would have to somehow keep the type instance in memory between requests and have some mechanism to correlate any received instance with the respective one held in memory.

However you handle this, I think you will need to make a change to your data contract type to include a HasChanged flag for each of your properties. Then on the client when they update a property they will also need to set the HasChanged flag.

However, this would need to be communicated to your clients as a convention to be adhered to when using your service, you would not be able to practically enforce this usage.

Of course, an alternative is for the service to interrogate any request against teh database to see what has changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your model being passed out of the service as Hugh suggests, another alternative would be to compare the received model with the current DB Data. It's a longhand method, and requires manual maintenance (not to mention addition DB hits), but it will get the job done. (Bear in mind, the below code is aircoded)

Assume this class:

```
public class MyData
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

You would have an `Update(MyData data)` method, and do something like the below:

```
public bool Update(MyData data)
{
  MyData current = null;

  //Do Database Retrieval here for current DB Data.

  if (MyData != null)
  {
    //Record already exists, update.
    if (current.Name != data.Name)
    {
       //Update the Name field for this record.
    }
    if (current.IsEnabled != data.IsEnabled)
    {
      //Update the IsEnabled field for this record.
    }
  }
  else
  {
    //Record doesn't exist.
    throw new ApplicationException("Record not found");
  }
}
```

You may also be able to do this middle block (checking each property) using Reflection. Either way, it's not pretty, but it does the job without needing to change the existing output from the service.